# delimit csv and strip whitespaces to generate new csv

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, trim, strip

I have a csv file content. Here the delimiter is | i want to remove spaces from the lines. I tried delimiting the files by | and strip each element of space however when writing it to a new csv the space get introduced back.Trying all this in python

| 1497/1         | ACERNO-1                  |         1 | 99000010119101   | RUCOPY :Database tree copy                         | LEGACY_DATA               |        283 | OFDB_IT_SIEP         |

```
import csv
aList=[]
workingdir = r"C:\Users\Akshay.Jain\Desktop\CAREER CONNECT"
csvfile = workingdir+r"\01_Wells.csv"
out = csv.writer(open("myfile.csv","w",newline=''),delimiter=',')

with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True,delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        for elements in row:

            elements.strip()
            aList.append(row)

        out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: there are spaces on both sides in between two ' | '
however they are not visible when i posted them here

Comment: I think you want `row = [e.strip() for e in row]` rather than your inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
 out.writerow(row)
```

writes the original `row` again. Try something like

```
 out.writerow(aList)
```

(with creation of `aList` moved into the loop and with adding `elements` to `aList`) or modify `row` directly, as pointed out by @mgilson in the comments:

```
for row in reader:
    row = [x.strip() for x in row]
    out.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
aList=[]
workingdir = r"C:\Users\Akshay.Jain\Desktop\CAREER CONNECT"
csvfile = workingdir+r"\01_Wells.csv"
out = csv.writer(open("myfile.csv","w",newline=''),delimiter=',')

with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True,delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        for elements in row:

            elements.strip()
            aList.append(elements[:-1])  # Add element by element, removing last item.

        out.writerow(aList[1: -1])  # Write list without first or last item, they are ","
```

Output:

```
1497/1,ACERNO-1,1,99000010119101,RUCOPY :Database tree copy,LEGACY_DATA,283,OFDB_IT_SIEP
```